# c# Array copy, resize

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array:

```
static Array results = new[] { new { Id, RoomCount, Cover, Space, Floor,
                                    FloorCount, NameHouse, Price, NameStreet } };
```

then I have the second one:

```
var res = (//.......//
select new { f.Id, f.RoomCount, f.Cover, f.Space, f.Floor, f.FloorCount,
             h.NameHouse, f.Price, s.NameStreet }).ToArray();
```

then I wanna copy res to results:

```
var lres = res.Length;
res.CopyTo(results, lres);
```

the lenght of the res varies, and the lenght of the results is fixed, cause it is just declared.

I got an exeption: the length of the dest array is too short.
I also tried to resize dest array:

```
var lres = res.Length;
Array.Resize(results, lres);
```

Also crashed: The type arguments for method `System.Array.Resize<T>(ref T[], int)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Any suggestions?

```
    public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    public static int Id { get; set; }
    public static int RoomCount { get; set; }
    public static string Cover { get; set; }
    public static int Space { get; set; }
    public static int Floor { get; set; }
    public static int FloorCount { get; set; }
    public static string NameHouse { get; set; }
    public static decimal Price { get; set; }
    public static string NameStreet { get; set; }

    static Array results = new[] { new { Id, RoomCount, Cover, Space, Floor,      FloorCount, NameHouse, Price, NameStreet } };  
 private Array FormData()
    {

       //some code
        var lng = ht.Length;

        while (lng != 0)
        {
            //
            var var = ht[lng - 1];
            lng--;


            var res = (from f in db.FlatSet
                           .Where(x => x.RoomCount >= rMin && x.RoomCount <= rMax)
                           .Where(x => x.Space >= sMin && x.Space <= sMax)
                           .Where(x => x.Floor >= fMin && x.Floor <= fMax)
                           .Where(x => x.FloorCount >= fcMin && x.FloorCount <= fcMax)
                           .Where(x => x.HouseTypeId == var)// || x.HouseTypeId == 2)
                           .Where(x => x.Price >= pMin && x.Price <= pMax)
                           .Where(x => x.Rent == r)
                       join h in db.HouseTypeSet on f.HouseTypeId equals h.Id
                       join s in db.StreetSet on f.StreetId equals s.Id
                       select new { f.Id, f.RoomCount, f.Cover, f.Space, f.Floor, f.FloorCount, h.NameHouse, f.Price, s.NameStreet }).ToArray();

            var lres = res.Length;
            Array.Resize(ref results, lres);

            res.CopyTo(results, lres);

        }
        return results;
    }


FIXED:
public class result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RoomCount { get; set; }
    public string Cover { get; set; }
    public int Space { get; set; }
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public int FloorCount { get; set; }
    public string NameHouse { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string NameStreet { get; set; }
}
public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DB_9AB8FB_lisogorEntities db = new DB_9AB8FB_lisogorEntities();


    List<result[]> myList = new List<result[]>();
    List<result> NewMyList = new List<result>();
}
  //////some code
 private List<result[]> FormData()//
    {
 int[] ht = (int[])arr;
        var lng = ht.Length;

        while (lng != 0)
        {
            //some code
            var var = ht[lng - 1];
            lng--;

            myList.Add((from f in db.FlatSet
                           .Where(x => x.RoomCount >= rMin && x.RoomCount <= rMax)
                           .Where(x => x.Space >= sMin && x.Space <= sMax)
                           .Where(x => x.Floor >= fMin && x.Floor <= fMax)
                           .Where(x => x.FloorCount >= fcMin && x.FloorCount <= fcMax)
                           .Where(x => x.HouseTypeId == var)// || x.HouseTypeId == 2)
                           .Where(x => x.Price >= pMin && x.Price <= pMax)
                           .Where(x => x.Rent == r)
                       join h in db.HouseTypeSet on f.HouseTypeId equals h.Id
                       join s in db.StreetSet on f.StreetId equals s.Id
                       select new result{ Id = f.Id, RoomCount = f.RoomCount, Cover = f.Cover, Space = f.Space, Floor = f.Floor, 
                                          FloorCount = f.FloorCount, NameHouse = h.NameHouse, Price = f.Price, NameStreet=s.NameStreet }).ToArray());

        }
        return myList;
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        var i = myList.Count;

        while (i != 0)
        {
            if (myList[i - 1].Length != 0)
            {
                var j = myList[i - 1].Length;
                while (j != 0)
                {
                    NewMyList.Add(myList[i - 1][j-1]);
                    j--;
                }
            }
            i--;
        }
        Results1.DataSource = NewMyList;
        Results1.DataBind();
    }
    }
```

Comment: May not be good code, but `results=results.Union(res).ToArray()` might help.

Comment: no method Union for arrays

Comment: Add: using System.Linq;

Comment: Why not use a `List`?

Answer (score 0):

you are  using  an anonymous type and the cocmpiler doesn't recognize how  it will infer the union of the two arrays as the  compiler should  know  the type of the object  for which  to create the instance
you are getting this  exception at

```
 Array.Resize<T>
```

method  which should  be strongly typed
Just to  understand  more

```
 class Program
  {
        static void Main(string[] args)
      {

          Array results = new[] { new { RoomCount = "2", Cover = "5", Space = "5", Floor = "5",    FloorCount = "5", NameHouse = "5", Price = "5", NameStreet = "5" } };            
        //with this line not cpmmented does not compile  
          Array.Resize(ref results, results.Length + 5);            

        String[] myArr = {"The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", 
        "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
        Array.Resize(ref myArr, myArr.Length + 5);

        MyTest[] resultsMyTest = new MyTest[] {new MyTest{RoomCount=3,Cover="Red"}};
        //here  it will work  as the compiler know  how to infer it 
        Array.Resize(ref resultsMyTest, results.Length + 5);            


    }
    public class  MyTest
    {
        public int RoomCount
        {
            get;
            set; 
        }
        public string Cover
        {
            get;
            set;  
        }

    }


}
```

Hope this help

Comment: if the length of both array is equal, everything works fine. the types of both array are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the explicit type in your `Array.Resize<T>`:

```
Array.Resize<String>(ref results, lres);
```

Then change `lres` to `0` because `lres` is the length of the array and the second parameter for `CopyTo` is the **starting index** of the **destination** not the length of the array:

```
res.CopyTo(results, 0);
```

The index is the starting index and you start with the last index and that's why destination array was not long enough.

Or use `Array.Copy()`:

```
Array.Copy(res, results, res.length);
```

Comment: @user2970104 specifying the Data Type in `Array.Resize<T>`? See update above.

Comment: I have anonymous type array, Can I use <T>?

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a solution for your current code as it is, go with this,

```
var arguments=new object[] { results, results.Length + res.Length };
        var method= typeof(Array).GetMethod("Resize").MakeGenericMethod(res.GetType().GetElementType());
        method.Invoke(null,arguments );
        var lastIndex = results.Length;
        results = arguments[0] as Array;
        res.CopyTo(results, lastIndex);
```

But I strongly suggest you not to do this. But create a `class` with all those properties and use a `List<YourClass>` for a clean and maintainable code. A generic `Array` of anonymous class won't take you long before you are forced to do a complete re-factoring.